# Accepting DB details from command line in spiring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, application.properties

I found these 2 lines in a project and wondering from where the values for `DB_URL` and `DB_USER`. These two variables are not declared in the `application.propeties` file.

If the value is coming from the command line how can I pass the value? Can someone show a sample command for how to pass the data for these 2 variables from command line?

```
spring.datasource.url=$(DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=$(DB_USER)
```

Comment: These are environment variables.  
You can set them in different ways, but that depends on your operating system.

Comment: For dev purpose, you can create application-local.properties and set a value there. Or you can put a default url in this way: `spring.datasource.url=$(DB_URL:defaultUrl}`